# Any similar `x` command of gdb in pdb?

Tags: python, pdb

With `gdb`, we can see the memory units, like `(gdb)   x  /**xb  address`, helping us understand how the variable reserved in computer actually. 
So can i do that with `pdb`? and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is No.

pdb has no such option to do this.('variable' called 'reference' may be better).

The variable in python is different from  C/C++,
For example:

the integer 1, in C his storage form:

```
   0000 0000 0000 0001
```

However, in python, 1 is not a pure number, It's a structure.

If you look at Python-2.7.13\Include\intobject.h

you will see this：

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    long ob_ival;
} PyIntObject;
```

I do not think there is a need to look at the storage form of a variable in python.

Sometimes we just need to know what a varible is.

In this situation, you can use `'p'` or `'pp'`.
Doc in https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html.

> p expression
>
> Evaluate the expression in the current context and print its value.
>
> pp expression
>
> Like the p command, except the value of the expression is pretty-printed using the pprint module.